# What happens when static_cast from derived class to base class?

Tags: c++, constructor, static-cast

While reading the C++ standard, I read that `static_cast` is a kind of **direct initialization** (C++ standard 8.5/15).
I think this means that during a `static_cast`, the corresponding **overloaded constructor** is called.
For example, there is a type B and type D derived from B, and an object `D d`. Then the expression `static_cast<B>(d)` is a `static_cast` expression.

As the standard means, this `static_cast` expression is a **direct initialization**. Does it mean that this will call the constructor of type `B` and return a new constructed object of type `B`?

---

**EDIT**
Another issue is how about `B & b = d` or `B b = d`? Does these two statements involve constructor of `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `static_cast` to an object type (i.e., not a cast to a reference or pointer type) will use the appropriate constructor to create a temporary object.

Comment: I have edited my post to raise another issue. Could you have a look?

Answer (score 1):

What they mean in the standard is that you can cast for example a float to an integer. At this point conversion will happen. You can say that the resulting `int` is directly initialized at this point.

If class that participates in casting have corresponding overloaded conversion, then yes, it will be called. I personally would not recommend to actively use this feature. Your code will be difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

No. Direct initialization means that each byte within the object of class B will be copied from object of class D, without constructors call.

Comment: No, that's not the case. In some situations `reinterpret_cast` does that, but `static_cast` is aware of the type system and respects it.